# Insert & Select Arabic data Android SQLite

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, arabic

I'm trying to create **arabic database** in android application and want to see how I can achieve that?

I know that I will have to do encoding and stuff. But I want to know if someone really tried to create non-english database and help me to do the best approach.

Comment: can't u convert that arabic data to english and can store that in database?i just guesss this....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could do it from eclipse without encoding, if I save the file as UTF-8 and write the arabic data normally..

Answer (score 3):

So for create `SQLite` best approach is use `SQLiteOpenHelper` and create your own class that extending from `SQLiteOpenHelper`, implements `onCreate()`, method and `onUpgrade()` method.

**Example how to create database:**

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "basic_login_system_database";
    protected static final String USER_TABLE_NAME = "User";
    protected static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    protected static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    protected static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    protected static final String KEY_SURNAME = "surname";
    protected static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";
    protected static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    protected static final String KEY_ADDRESS = "adress";
    protected static final String KEY_AGE = "age";


    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }       

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_USER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + USER_TABLE_NAME + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + KEY_SURNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + KEY_PASSWORD + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL, "
                + KEY_ADDRESS + " TEXT, "
                + KEY_AGE + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_USER_TABLE);
    }

    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        String DELETE_USER_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + USER_TABLE_NAME;
        db.execSQL(DELETE_USER_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);       
    }
}
```

And you must set encoding for `Arabic` characters because implicitly is it set on `utf-8`.

`private static final String ENCODING_SETTING = "PRAGMA encoding ='windows-1256'";`

And you set it in your `onOpen()` method.

```
@Override
public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
   if (!db.isReadOnly()) {
      db.execSQL(ENCODING_SETTING);
   }
}
```

Then for retrieve data from your database just use `Cursor` with methods `rawQuery()` or `query()`.

**Example:** `Cursor c = db.raQuery(SELECT_STATEMENT, null);`

For insert data use `insert()` method of `SQLiteDatabase`.