# How to read foreign characters from a cell in excel sheet using Apache POI and store them in database using SQLITE?

Tags: java, excel, sqlite, apache-poi

I am using **Apache POI** to read the text values from the cells in an excel sheet.

```
String str = cell.getStringCellValue();
```

However, when the cell contains text *other than* English, say , from any **foreign language**, it does not get stored in the string variable. What am I supposed to do in order to make it compatible with **unicode** characters as well?

Moreover, can I store them safely in a database using **Sqlite**?

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11080067/insert-select-arabic-data-android-sqlite

Comment: yes but what should I do to make it generally readable ( for all foreign text) instead of just Arabic?

Comment: Apache POI works just fine with all unicode text. Are you sure you're not breaking things when you try to output the unicode to the console or another system?

Comment: Please let me know how to ensure I don't do so?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse IDE change the encoding to UTF-8. 
Project > Properties > Resources > Text file encoding > Other > UTF-8

Use the data formatter as well.

```
DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
LOGGER.info(formatter.formatCellValue(cell));
```